# I'm unable to show that function has discontinuity of second kind at points different from 0.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

[image: book by SC Malik and Savita Arora]
I'm unable to show that function has discontinuity of second kind at points different from 0.

Comment: maybe you should tell what your textbook's definition of "continuity of first/second kind" are. Maybe also you should type the question instead of a snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Verify that for $x>0,$

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1+x,&x \text { rational }\\1, &x \text { irrational } \end{cases}$$

Could $f$ have a one-sided limit at any positive number?